# How find duplicates of the same id but different date with SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a datatable like that :

| id | line | datedt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 01/01/2021 |
| 123 | 2 | 01/01/2021 |
| 123 | 3 | 01/01/2021 |
| 777 | 1 | 13/04/2020 |
| 777 | 2 | 13/04/2020 |
| 123 | 1 | 12/04/2021 |
| 123 | 2 | 12/04/2021 |
| 888 | 1 | 01/07/2020 |
| 888 | 2 | 01/07/2020 |
| 452 | 1 | 05/01/2020 |
| 888 | 1 | 02/05/2021 |
| 888 | 2 | 02/05/2021 |

I'd like to obtain a result like that, ie : the nb of same id with differents dates.
Example we can find 123 with 2 diffents dates, 888 too, but only date for 777 and 452

| id | nb |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 |
| 777 | 1 |
| 888 | 2 |
| 452 | 1 |

How could I get that ?

Hope it's clear :)

Thanks you

Comment: Hint: count distinct.

Comment: Explain the **line** column. There may be a more efficient way than "select distinct" depending on what that extra column means.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id , count(distinct datedt) as nb
from table
group by id
```